# Can not run TestNG suit in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

Here is my pom file for Java Selenium WebDriver Maven project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/wwwRegression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/betaRegression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.50.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What I need to do - run certain test suite from cmd on windows. From the project dir I tried to use different variations of commands:

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=wwwRegression
mvn test -Dsuite=wwwRegression
mvn surefire:test -DsuiteXmlFile=wwwRegression
```

But all the time both of the test suites are executing.
Does anybody have any ideas how to run one certain test suite ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a property in the pom file to be able to pass through the command prompt.

Modify the pom file like below.

```
<properties
    <testngFiles>src/test/resources/wwwRegression.xml,src/test/resources/betaRegression.xml</testngFiles>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${testngFiles}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can run the test by using

> mvn -U clean install -DtestngFiles=src/test/resources/wwwRegression.xml

Note: Surefire can take multiple testNG XML files as comma separated values.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
I have done what you had suggested. I got test failed: there was an error in the forked process.
@Sighil

Comment: Kindly give the full path to the XML file and try again. I have edited the answer

Comment: That didn't help. I tried to run it with the full path like you suggested. Here is what I got.

C:\Users\Yurii\IdeaProjects\my_project>mvn -U clean install -testngFiles=src/test/resources/wwwRegression.out.xml
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] The specified user toolchains file does not exist: C:\Users\Yurii\IdeaProjects\my_project\estngFiles=src\test\resources\wwwRegression.out.xml

Comment: Then I added "-D" before file path, like this:

Comment: mvn -U clean install -DtestngFiles=src/test/resources/wwwRegression.out.xml

Comment: Did it work.. I edited the answer in mobile and missed the -D

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project my_project_automation: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file C:\Users\Yurii\IdeaProjects\my_project\src\test\resources\wwwRegression.out.xml is not a valid file

Comment: Check the file name - wwwRegression.out.xml -- > wwwRegression.xml

Comment: Yes, I tried. The same error. Have no clue what's wrong...(

Comment: can you post the post the contents of  the required file ?

Comment: I posted my xml files...@Sighil

Comment: Are you sure that  wwwRegression.xml file is present at C:\Users\Yurii\IdeaProjects\my_project\src\test\resources\   ? Also, can u try inputting the second file